# Time difference between 2 rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.5

I have the following table

| TransactionID | UserID | TransactionDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | '2021-04-22 11:00:00' |
| 2 | 2 | '2021-04-22 11:00:11' |
| 3 | 1 | '2021-04-22 11:00:22' |
| 4 | 3 | '2021-04-22 11:00:33' |
| 5 | 3 | '2021-04-22 11:00:44' |
| 6 | 1 | '2021-04-22 11:00:55' |

I want to see the time difference between transactions for each UserID.
Something like this:

| TransactionID | UserID | TransactionDateTime | TimeDifference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | '2021-04-22 11:00:00' | NULL |
| 2 | 2 | '2021-04-22 11:00:11' | NULL |
| 3 | 1 | '2021-04-22 11:00:22' | 00:22 |
| 4 | 3 | '2021-04-22 11:00:33' | NULL |
| 5 | 3 | '2021-04-22 11:00:44' | 00:11 |
| 6 | 1 | '2021-04-22 11:00:55' | 00:33 |

Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *,
       SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, 
                                 TransactionDateTime,
                                 LAG(TransactionDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID
                                                                ORDER BY TransactionDateTime))) TimeDifference
FROM table
ORDER BY TransactionDateTime
```

> but I'm using MySQL 5.5 version and the PARTITION BY function isn't supported. Maybe there is other way? – Varuzhan Stepanyan

```sql
SELECT t1.*, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t2.TransactionDateTime, t1.TransactionDateTime)) TimeDifference
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID 
                 AND t1.TransactionDateTime > t2.TransactionDateTime
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table t3
                   WHERE t1.UserID = t3.UserID 
                     AND t1.TransactionDateTime > t3.TransactionDateTime
                     AND t3.TransactionDateTime > t2.TransactionDateTime )
ORDER BY t1.TransactionID;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=b7d43521afc8fe6623f152343bb88d4b

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using MySQL 5.5 version and the PARTITION BY function isn't supported. Maybe there is other way?

Comment: @VaruzhanStepanyan Updated. PS. Always report the version if it is not actual.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a correlated subquery to get the previous date/time in older versions of MySQL:

```
select t.*,
       timediff(TransactionDateTime, prev_TransactionDateTime) as timedifference
from (select t.*,
             (select max(t2.TransactionDateTime)
              from t t2
              where t2.UserId = t.UserId and
                    t2.TransactionDateTime < t.TransactionDateTime
             ) as prev_TransactionDateTime
      from t
     ) t;
```